# How can deanonymize me? vpn tor vpn

Tags: deanonymization

I want to use connection vpn1 - tor - vpn2, where vpn1 and vpn2 I will buy with openvpn connection more likely, entry node of tor 
will be on my raspberry pi (in my home) with disabled logs, I'm going use this chain to connect to the vps server, I'm not going to
to do anything illegal. For this chain, I will use whonix on virtualbox, Linux on the host, Linux on the entry node and Linux on vps.
To connect to vps, I want to use most likely remmina or another client and rdp or vnc connection. How can deanonymize me most power people?
If they will do this. I research anonymity of internet, and for this I am asking this question. I need it
for these purposes. Vps will probably be interrupted, after each connection I want delete logs for connecting to it.

Comment: e.g. they will de-anonymize you via payments for your VPN/VPS... so using Tor in this setup may be pointless.

Comment: one suggestion to think about in general: it's not guaranteed that a more complex setup will be more secure, it is even more possible that you make a mistake (or suffer from a software-bug) and you are screwed.

Comment: "e.g. they will de-anonymize you via payments for your VPN/VPS... so using Tor in this setup may be pointless", it is excluded as well as any other methods that are not related to my first message are excluded. Tor doesn't exchange path during connection if is using chain vpn-tor-vpn with whonix to connection to vps as I know (like in IRC chat), can they see time of connection to vps (31 minutes, etc) and see what relay node and entry node were connected this 31 minutes? And deanonymize?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you want to use such config, if you don't want to do smth illegal (even SilkR0ad creator didn't have paranoia like you XD). Firstly, it will take you to reach simple website about 2 minutes, and you won't be able to search comfortably.

The idea to use Raspberry Pi is very good, so I suggest you to set up R Pi, and from it connect to Tor(if you need this setup to visit .onion links). 
If you only want to search anonymously and get rid off BigBrother, you can config openvpn server or purchase NordVPN (remember, it is better to use cryptocurrency as a payment method, more secure and it is less chance that "THEY" will trace you) and plugin Firefox to use DuckDuckGo search engine. If you done with your job, you can easily break R Pi and drop it to the further trash box.
Hope this would help you :)